# How to define multiple containers in declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jnlp

I was using [kuberntes-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin). In its README it has given how to write scripted pipeline with multiple container images, like

```
podTemplate(label: 'mypod', containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'maven', image: 'maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat'),
    containerTemplate(name: 'golang', image: 'golang:1.8.0', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat')
  ]) {
    node('mypod') {
```

I tried the following for declarative pipeline.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      //cloud 'kubernetes'
      label 'mypod'
      containerTemplate {
        name 'maven'
        image 'maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine'
        ttyEnabled true
        command 'cat'
      }
      containerTemplate {
        name 'containtertwo'
        image 'someimage'
        ttyEnabled true

      }
    }
  }
```

It creates a pod with only one container.

how to use multiple containerTemplates with declarative pipeline?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: using scripted pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

This isnt a solution to your problem, but is some information I found after looking.

The [KubernetesDeclarativeAgent](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/csanchez/jenkins/plugins/kubernetes/pipeline/KubernetesDeclarativeAgent.java#L28) only has a single `containerTemplate`. Whichever `containerTemplate` is at the bottom of your collection of containers will be the one that is used.

In your example it will be `containtertwo`.

You cant have multiple top level `agents`, and you cant have multiple `kubernetes` within an agent. And now you cant have multiple containers. I would prefer if an error or warning of some kind was thrown for this.

There are 2 work arounds I can think of. If you must use declarative, then you can add an `agent` to your `stage`, but this can lead to its own issues. The other is the scripted pipeline, which is what I am going to do.

The documentation on this leaves much to be desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive that with the help of a pod template file. I use the following one to deploy my app on kubernetes:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    label: docker
spec:
  containers:
  - name: docker
    image: jenkins/jnlp-agent-docker
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'
      name: docker-socket
  - name: kubectl
    image: bitnami/kubectl
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
  volumes:
  - name: docker-socket
    hostPath:
      path: '/var/run/docker.sock'
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
```

Then use this in a declarative pipeline:

```
stage('Deploy') {
  when {
    anyOf { branch 'master'; tag '' }
  }
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      defaultContainer 'kubectl' // All `steps` instructions will be executed by this container
      yamlFile 'path/to/pod/template.yaml'
    }
  }
  steps {
    container('docker') {
      sh 'echo This is executed in the docker container'
    }
  }
}
```

You can also specify the template in the Jenkinsfile with the help of `yaml` option instead of `yamlFile`, you just need to use a multiline string there.

Answer (score 0):

True , I am unable to use multiple containerTemplate.

I see there is something called as 'containerTemplates', and I see even this allows only one containerTemplate inside it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35485706)